# Adding multiple columns to a table in sqllite

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite

Can i add multiple columns to a table in a single query execution, using alter table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,you can't add multiple columns in single query execution. SQLite supports a limited subset of ALTER TABLE.therefore you have to add them one by one.

[see documentation at sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: @Ashwani how u did that for multiple columns adding by alter the table in sqlite, im facing same issue now, could tell me?

Comment: @Anilkumar: one at a time

Comment: BOOL checkColumn = [self checkColumnExists];
        if (!checkColumn)
        {
            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE recentCall ADD COLUMN calduration VARCHAR(15)"];
        NSString *updateSQL1 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE recentCall ADD COLUMN transfer_number VARCHAR(15)"];
            NSString *updateSQL2 = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE recentCall ADD COLUMN connected_to VARCHAR(15)"];

Comment: i done like this, but its not adding @Milind Anantwar

Comment: i am trying to add two columns, i mean altering table with two new columns for existed table

Comment: @Anilkumar: it is hard to find the issue in code you have shared.

Comment: could u give example for alter the table by adding multiple columns same time?

Comment: @Anilkumar: check solutions given here http://forums.realsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37260